# regex to match numbers in specific location

Tags: regex

I want to match a string using regex, the string I wanna match is **xxxxx_S_xxxxxx** (where x are numbers), I want to match the three numbers closer to *S* to the left and the four numbers closer to the right.

Let's say I have **c1123_S_1234** so I want to match **123_S_1234**

This is what I tried:

`(^[0-9]{3}$+_S_[0-9])`

but it's not working, not matching anything, any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you use anchors? Use `\d{3}_S_\d{4}`

Comment: Thank you, I used the anchors supposing it'll locate the match to the numbers closer to _S_, I'm new to this so...
It means, the matching will always start from the S? (or the matching I put in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex engine parses the text from left to right, i.e. it checks the position at the start of string for a match first, if it does not match, it goes on to the right and checks the rest of the string.  The pattern sequences are also parsed from left to right, if you have `(^[0-9]{3}$+_S_[0-9])`, first, the `^` will be checked, i.e. the start of string. And as there is only one start of string, the regex could potentially only match at the start of string, but the `$` end of string anchor presence in the middle of the regex makes it a pattern that matches no string.

That means you can't tell the regex engine to find a `_S_` substring and then start consuming text to the right or left.

You need

```py
[0-9]{3}_S_[0-9]{4}
\d{3}_S_\d{4}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RbLPTC/1). `[0-9]{3}` searches for three consecutive digits, then there must be `_S_` right after, and then any four digits must follow.